Ubuntu: Use anacron and rsync for monthly backups to external drive
My goal is to write monthly backups of my ubuntu /home/ directory to an external drive, which after connecting it to the computer I can see at /media/ironman/Elements. To this end I use rsync.
The external drive is not always mounted, so I made an interactive script, prompting me to mount the drive when it is not. I want to schedule this script with anacron because my laptop is regularly shut down. I think that my setup does not work because of the interactive part: when I run the script from the command line, I can naturally see its output in the same command line. However, anacron is not run from the command line.
This is the script in /home/ironman/scripts/backup_anacron.sh
#!/bin/bash

# Variables
SOURCE_DIR="/home/ironman"
TARGET_DIR="/media/ironman/Elements/backup_$(date +%Y%m%d)"
EXCLUDES="--exclude=\"lost+found\" --exclude=\".cache\""
RSYNC_CMD="rsync -a --info=progress2 $EXCLUDES $SOURCE_DIR/ $TARGET_DIR"


# Function to check if the drive is mounted
check_mount() {
    if grep -qs "/media/ironman/Elements " /proc/mounts; then
        echo "Backup drive is mounted."
        return 0
    else
        return 1
    fi
}

# Check whether backup drive has enough free space
check_space() {
    # Get available space on target drive in kilobytes
    available_space=$(df --output=avail "/media/ironman/Elements" | tail -1)
    # Get required space for the source directory in kilobytes
    required_space=$(du -sk "$SOURCE_DIR" | cut -f1)
    
    if [ "$available_space" -ge "$required_space" ]; then
        echo "Enough space on backup drive. Required: $required_space KB, Available: $available_space KB."
        return 0
    else
        echo "Not enough space on backup drive. Required: $required_space KB, Available: $available_space KB. Manual backup necessary"
        echo $RSYNC_CMD
        exit 1
    fi
}

# Initial check
check_mount
if [ $? -eq 1 ]; then

    # If the drive is not mounted, prompt the user
    echo "Please mount drive within one minute."

    # Wait for up to 60 seconds for the drive to be mounted
    for i in {1..60}; do
    
        # check every second if drive is mounted
        sleep 1
        check_mount
        if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
        
            # if enough space available, execute rsync, else print error message
        check_space
        if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
                eval $RSYNC_CMD
                exit 0 
            fi
        fi
    done
fi


# If the drive is still not mounted after 60 seconds, print an error message
if [ $? -eq 1 ]; then
    echo "Backup drive is not mounted. Could not backup /home/ironman/. Command for manual backup:"
    echo $RSYNC_CMD
    exit 1
fi

# if enough space available, execute rsync, else exit script
check_space
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    eval $RSYNC_CMD
    exit 0
fi

I added the following line at the end of /etc/anacrontab:
@monthly   15  backup.monthly nice /home/ironman/scripts/backup_anacron.sh
When I force the monthly tasks to run with /usr/sbin/anacron -n -f cron.monthly, nothing happens. What am I doing wrong?

As Phil says, stuff running from [ana]cron is NOT running in your interactive session. You didn't say what your interactive session looks like. If you are running a Linux desktop environment, it will probably support notify-send  which allows you to send a prompt - but is ONLY a notification (does not provide a means for you to tell the script to continue).
If instead you create separate scripts to

Check if the last backup was over N days ago / if the drive is mounted / launch the backup if appropriate / send a notification that the backup is overdue or needs started

perform the backup


Then you might have a viable workflow here.
(hint: https://man.archlinux.org/man/mountpoint.1, https://man.archlinux.org/man/core/util-linux/lsblk.8.en)

[Ana]cron does not run in your (or any other) interactive session.
It's meant to run deep in the background, well away from anything that might "interfere" with it, like waiting [forever] for a User to respond to a prompt.
You'd be better off writing your script to just go ahead and do the job - mount the device, take the backup and unmount the device again afterwards - and, of course, handle all the errors that might happen along the way.
